# PowerShell script execution with alias in other DNS Zone

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script hosted on Windows 2016 server. This script is used by all IT teams.
Currently, to run the script, users use the following command:

```
powershell \\ServerName.mydomain1\Share\MyScript.ps1
```

Everything is working fine.

I would like to create a DNS alias like MyScript.mydomain2.
I can access to the server correctly ussing the alias. But, if I want to run the script using

```
powershell \\MyScript.mydomain2\Share\MyScript.ps1
```

it does not work. I've got an error told me I must sign the script.

If I use the serveur name instead alias, all is working. If I create an alias in the same domain than the server, all is working. If the alias is stored in another DNS domain, I've got the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the SPN on the server. Because an alias is used, a new SPN "HOST/MyScript.mydomain2" have to be added.
It workss fine now.
Thank you for your help,

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

The new UNC path is not among the locations your systems trust for script execution. To resolve the issue you can either:

- Sign the script.
- Add `\\MyScript.mydomain2\Share` to the list of trusted locations (more specifically to the "Local Intranet" zone, e.g. via group policy). See the [Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/10/29/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-a-shared-directory/) blog for details.
- Override the execution policy when invoking the script:

  ```
  powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\MyScript.mydomain2\Share\MyScript.ps1
  ```

  Beware that overriding the execution policy will only work if it isn't defined via local or group policies.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try to add \\MyScript.mydomain2\Share to trusted sites in Internet settings (Value 2) but it does not work. I tried to put the setting on Workstation and user but Nothing works. I still got the same error...

Comment: You need to add it to "Local Intranet", not "Trusted Sites". [See here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/10/29/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-a-shared-directory/)